# KiCad -- layout, how to remove extra vertexes from filled zones

Tags: kicad

In KiCad's layout tool, we can add a vertex to the outline of a "filled zone" with the "Insert" key. Sometimes I put in too many, change my mind etc, and they get annoying. How to remove them?

Comment: right click and pick remove vertex.

Comment: oh, duh. never noticed that. thanks!

Comment: Of course, you could also delete the entire zone and re-draw it with fewer vertices, but I think deleting the vertex from the context menu is easier!

Comment: well yeah. I've been using it for a while actually, completely overlooked it

Answer (score 2):

As @Hearth pointed out, this is actually trivial. Right-clicking directly on the vertex (vs right-clicking on the outline but not the vertex) adds the "Remove Corner" item to the right-click menu.